# Media player create method does not seem to work on my project, causes my app to crash on launching the first activity. somebody help me plz

Tags: android

Util class holding Media player create method:

{

```
private static ArrayList<Song> allSongs;
private static ArrayList<Song> favouriteSongs;
private static int id = 0;
Context context;

public Util(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Util() {
    if (allSongs == null){
        allSongs = new ArrayList<>();
        initializingAllSongs();
    }

    if (favouriteSongs == null){
        favouriteSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}



public static ArrayList<Song> getAllSongs() {
    return allSongs;
}

public static ArrayList<Song> getFavouriteSongs() {
    return favouriteSongs;
}
public void addToFavSongs(Song song){
    favouriteSongs.add(song);
}
public void removeFromFavSongs(Song song){
    favouriteSongs.remove(song);
}

private void  initializingAllSongs(){

    int songNumber = 0;
    String songTitle = "";
    String songLyrics = " ";
    MediaPlayer audioPlayer ;

    id++;
    songNumber = 1;
    songTitle = "Sample song Title ";
    songLyrics = "Sample lyrics Sample lyrics \n" +
            " Sample lyrics Sample lyrics \n" +
            "Sample lyrics Sample lyrics \n" +
            " Sample lyrics Sample lyrics";
    audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    audioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audio);
    allSongs.add(new Song(id, songNumber, songTitle, songLyrics, audioPlayer ));




    id++;
    songNumber = 2;
    songTitle = "Sample song Title ";
    songLyrics  = "Sample lyrics Sample lyrics \n" +
            " Sample lyrics Sample lyrics \n" +
            "Sample lyrics Sample lyrics \n" +
            " Sample lyrics Sample lyrics";
    audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    audioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audi);
    allSongs.add(new Song(id, songNumber, songTitle, songLyrics, audioPlayer ));


}
```

}

MainActivity (part of it):

```
     recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.songsRecView);

     SongRecViewAdapter adapter = new SongRecViewAdapter(this);
     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

     Util util = new Util();
     ArrayList<Song> allSongs = new ArrayList<>();
     allSongs = util.getAllSongs();
     adapter.setSongs(allSongs);
```

Logcat:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
at com.example.mrfpc.Util.initializingAllSongs(Util.java:62)
at com.example.mrfpc.Util.(Util.java:22)
at com.example.mrfpc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)

Comment: Rather than making instance  of `mediaPlayer` for every song, declare a single instance in `MainActivity` and using `Title` play the song.

Comment: Thanks for answering  Swapnil Padaya but the main point of concern is at the create method which throws an exception. The logcat I provided contain links to where the problems originate from but i cant solve them.

Comment: `Util util = new Util();` when you create an instance try passing the `ApplicationContext()` of `MainActivity` and in util `.create(/* MainAcitvity context*/, raw file)` Try this out.   Util(Context ctx) <-- `Constructor` and when you create instance of `Util`  it should be like `Util util = new Util(context.getApplicationContext())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you haven't initialized `Context` in the constructor your initializing in your activity.

Add `Context` in second constructor and remove the one that has it, initialize it there and it won't throw it anymore.

Comment: @Phillips if it worked, please mark it as accepted :)